# Integrating Face Recognition in Android App with BiometricPrompt

Tags: android, kotlin

I am currently working on adding face recognition capabilities to my Android app using BiometricPrompt, but I am facing issues with its implementation. Here is the relevant part of my code:

```
fun isUserBiometricEligible(context: Context): Boolean {
    val biometricManager: BiometricManager = BiometricManager.from(context)

    return when (biometricManager.canAuthenticate(BiometricManager.Authenticators.BIOMETRIC_STRONG)) {
        BiometricManager.BIOMETRIC_SUCCESS -> true
        else -> false
    }
}

@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
fun configureBiometricValidation(
    activity: AppCompatActivity,
    onAuthenticationSucceeded: () -> Unit,
    onAuthenticationFailed: () -> Unit,
    onAuthenticationError: (errorCode: Int, errString: CharSequence) -> Unit
) {
    executor = ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(activity)

    biometricPrompt = BiometricPrompt(activity, executor,
        object : BiometricPrompt.AuthenticationCallback() {
            override fun onAuthenticationError(errorCode: Int, errString: CharSequence) {
                super.onAuthenticationError(errorCode, errString)
                onAuthenticationError(errorCode, errString)
            }

            override fun onAuthenticationSucceeded(result: BiometricPrompt.AuthenticationResult) {
                super.onAuthenticationSucceeded(result)

                val cryptoObject: BiometricPrompt.CryptoObject? = result.cryptoObject

                if (cryptoObject?.cipher == null)
                    onAuthenticationError(-1, "")
                else{
                    val sharedPreferencesHelper = SharedPreferencesHelper(activity)
                    BiometricsSharedPreferences(sharedPreferencesHelper).setBiometricState(true)
                    onAuthenticationSucceeded()
                }

            }

            override fun onAuthenticationFailed() {
                super.onAuthenticationFailed()
                onAuthenticationFailed()
            }
        })

    promptInfo = BiometricPrompt.PromptInfo.Builder()
        .setTitle(activity.getString(R.string.prompt_dialog_info_title))
        .setDescription(activity.getString(R.string.prompt_dialog_info_description))
        .setNegativeButtonText(activity.getString(R.string.prompt_dialog_info_use_app_password))
        .build()

    generateSecretKey(KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(
        KEY_ALIAS,
        KeyProperties.PURPOSE_ENCRYPT or KeyProperties.PURPOSE_DECRYPT)
        .setBlockModes(KeyProperties.BLOCK_MODE_CBC)
        .setEncryptionPaddings(KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_PKCS7)
        .setUserAuthenticationRequired(true)
        .setInvalidatedByBiometricEnrollment(true)
        .build())

    val cipher = getCipher()
    val secretKey = getSecretKey()
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey)
    biometricPrompt.authenticate(promptInfo,
        BiometricPrompt.CryptoObject(cipher))

}
```

I have tried forcing a true return inside the isUserBiometricEligible() function, but the issue persists. The problem does not seem to be device-specific, as I can use face recognition in other apps on the same device. Currently, I am able to authenticate using a fingerprint with this code, but not with face recognition.

Questions:

Is there any additional configuration required specifically for face recognition that I might be missing?
Could this issue be related to the way I am initializing BiometricPrompt or the CryptoObject?
Are there known compatibility issues with certain Android versions or devices for face recognition using BiometricPrompt?
Any insights or suggestions to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried opting into weak authenticators: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/biometrics/BiometricPrompt.Builder?hl=en#setAllowedAuthenticators(int) ?

Comment: Related: you might try using the non-`CryptoObject` version of `authenticate()` to see if you get face recognition. On most hardware, face recognition is considered a weak biometric, and that might not be sufficient for your `CryptoObject` needs.

Comment: My issue was solved with both of your suggestions. Nice combo! Thanks :)

Comment: Glad they helped! You might consider posting an answer to your own question, showing what specifically you modified!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I encountered two issues and solved them as follows:

Allowing Weak or Strong Biometric Authentication:
The problem was resolved by permitting both weak and strong biometric authentications. This is achieved by adding the following line in the promptInfo configuration:

```
.setAllowedAuthenticators(BiometricManager.Authenticators.BIOMETRIC_STRONG or BiometricManager.Authenticators.BIOMETRIC_WEAK)
```

This line enables the application to accept either strong or weak biometric inputs, increasing its flexibility and user accessibility.

Removing the CryptoObject from BiometricPrompt Authentication:
The second issue was resolved by simply removing the CryptoObject from the authentication process. Instead of passing a CryptoObject to biometricPrompt.authenticate, only the promptInfo object is passed:

```
biometricPrompt.authenticate(promptInfo)
```

This change simplifies the authentication process when the cryptographic operations are not required for your specific use case.

By implementing these two solutions, I was able to make the biometric authentication more flexible and straightforward for my application's needs.